# Multiple Tables and Relationships in MySQL Selection

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database for product SKU's and options related to those SKU_ID's.

I have a product, say, $productId, and it is a T'Shirt with 3 colors (Pink, Purple, Black). Here is the database information (only showing relevant info):

```
tbl_skus
SKU_ID          SKU_ProductID
  62                 32
  63                 32
  64                 32
  62                 32
  62                 32
  67                 32

tbl_skuoption_rel
optn_rel_SKU_ID      optn_rel_Option_ID
    62                     32
    62                     34
    63                     34
    63                     33
    64                     35
    64                     32
    65                     35
    65                     33
    66                     36
    66                     32
    67                     36
    67                     33

tbl_skuoptions
option_ID     option_Type_ID      option_Name      option_Sort
   32                5               Small              1
   33                5               Medium             2
   34                6               Pink               1
   35                6               Purple             2
   36                6               Black              3
```

I don't get along well with joining in my query. If that's what I need to do to make this work, then so be it. Here's my attempt:

```
$SKU_QUERY = mysql_query("SELECT SKU_ID FROM tbl_skus WHERE SKU_ProductID = '$productId'") or die(mysql_error());
$SKU_NUM_ROWS = mysql_num_rows($SKU_QUERY);
if($SKU_NUM_ROWS > 0) {
    while($SKU_OBJECT = mysql_fetch_object($SKU_QUERY)) {
        $SKU_ID = $SKU_OBJECT->SKU_ID;
        $REL_OPTION_QUERY = mysql_query("SELECT optn_rel_Option_ID FROM tbl_skuoption_rel WHERE optn_rel_SKU_ID = '$SKU_ID' LIMIT 0,1") or die(mysql_error());
        $REL_OPTION_NUM_ROWS = mysql_num_rows($REL_OPTION_QUERY);
        if($REL_OPTION_NUM_ROWS > 0) {
            while($REL_OPTION_OBJECT = mysql_fetch_object($REL_OPTION_QUERY)) {
                $OPTION_ID = $REL_OPTION_OBJECT->optn_rel_Option_ID;
                $OPTIONS_QUERY = mysql_query("SELECT option_Name FROM tbl_skuoptions WHERE option_ID = '$OPTION_ID' AND option_Type_ID = '6' ORDER BY option_sort LIMIT 0,1") or die(mysql_error());
                $OPTIONS_NUM_ROWS = mysql_num_rows($OPTIONS_QUERY);
                if($OPTIONS_NUM_ROWS > 0) {
                    $OPTIONS_OBJECT = mysql_fetch_object($OPTIONS_QUERY);
                    echo "$OPTIONS_OBJECT->option_Name, ";
                }
            }
        }
    }        
}
```

Here's my results:

> Pink, Purple, Purple, Black, Black

If I can take off the extra color names, then I'll be fine. I won't be doing more than five or six colors max so any concerns about loading isn't necessary in my opinion. Once again, if it's ONLY possible by joining, then I'll do it. My 10 minute attempt seems to prove I can do it this way.

For now I am trying to create a string of the options that deal with a color.

My results **should** be

> Pink, Purple, Black

It's a simple result, but I will extend this afterwards.

Comment: Could you describe the result you're looking for in a few sentences?

Comment: so overall, what do you want to happen? because you seem to explain too much about the background that you forgot what you wanted to ask for

Comment: My apologies. For now all I am trying to do is create a string of the options that deal with a color. So you see my current results is "Pink, Purple, Purple, Black, Black" and my results **should** be "Pink, Purple, Black". I know it's a simple result for such a crazy thing, but I will extend off this afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think using `join` would make this much easier:

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.option_Name 
FROM 
    tbl_skus s
    JOIN tbl_skuoption_rel sor ON sor.optn_rel_SKU_ID = s.SKU_ID
    JOIN tbl_skuoptions o 
        ON o.option_ID = sor.optn_rel_Option_ID 
        AND o.option_Type_ID = '6'
WHERE s.SKU_ProductID = '$productId'
ORDER BY o.option_sort
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you very much. Would up-vote if I had enough rep.

Comment: @lxndr Hey look at that... you mysteriously now have enough rep to up-vote... ;-)